# Increase in volume of solution in neutralization reaction and its effect on weak acid

Tags: acid-base

If 100ml of 1M acetic acid and 20ml 0.01M NaOH is taken in a reaction medium,they will neutralize each other. I don't know for sure if this reaction is completely neutralized or not just took as an example. Now the water molecules produced in this reaction would increase slight amount of volume though they were present in the medium as ions but let us consider that the formation of molecule made those more spacious. Weak acids have a very low amount of dissoiation constant which depends on the concentration of the acid. How significant will be the effect of the slight change in volume of the solution to the dissociation of acid? I mean since the volume is increasing,concentration of the acid (ions) is supposed to decrease. Again due to the dissociation constant being too low, how significant will the change in volume of the solution be in the dissociation of acid?

Comment: Short answer: Not very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

«Not very much», as stated by `@Nisarg Bhavasar`'s comment below the OP's question intrigued me to provide an estimate about how much, or better, how little the relative amount of «new water», obtained by the neutralization is.  The estimation assumes the absence of [water's autoprotolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water), and indeed, the amount is tiny.

- With the neutalization of

  $$ \ce{HOAc + NaOH -> H2O + NaOAc} $$

  and the assumption of $\ce{HOAc}$ ($\pu{1 M}, \pu{100 mL}$) and $\ce{NaOH}$ ($\pu{0.01 M}, \pu{20 mL}$) it is evident that the molar amount of lye is the limiting factor in this reaction:

  $$ c = \frac{n}{V}  \leftrightarrow n = c \cdot V$$

  $$ n(\ce{NaOH}) = \pu{10 \times 10^{-3} mol/L\,  \cdot\, 20 \times 10^{-3} L} = \pu{200 \times 10^{-6} mol}$$

  This equally is the amount of «new water»,
- Assuming a molecular weight of water of $\pu{18.0 g/mol}$ ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_(data_page))) and for simplicity a density of $\approx \pu{1.0 g/cm³}$ (*loc. cit.*), the concentration of water *in* water equates to

  $$c = \frac{\pu{1000 g}} {\pu{18.0 g/mol}} = \pu{55.6 mol/L}$$
- With a molar mass of $\pu{60.1 g/mol}$ ($\ce{HOAc}$) and $\pu{40.0 g/mol}$ $\ce{NaOH}$ and the molar concentrations given, an estimation still may assume for the density of these solutions $\approx \pu{1.0 g/mL}$ ([reference](https://www.chembuddy.com/?left=CASC&right=density_tables)). Thus, as they total for $\pu{120 mL}$, this is equivalent to $\approx \pu{120 g}$ «old water»,  or a molar amount of $\pu{6.67 mol}$.
- It is time to set these quantities into context.

  $$ \mathrm{ratio} = \frac{ \mathrm{\mbox{new water}} } { \mathrm{\mbox{old water} }} =  \frac{ \pu{200 \times 10^{-6} mol} } {\pu{6.67 mol}} = \pu{29.99 \times 10^{-6}} \approx \pu{3.0 \times 10^{-3}\%} $$

This is like *for every 33350 molecules of water present by the reagent solutions, there is one molecule generated by the neutralization reaction between the acid and the base*.

The autoprotolysis of water at room temperature equates $K_w = [\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}] = \pu{10^{-14} mol^2/L^2}$.  Thus, in *neuter* water at room temperature and pH = 7, the concentration of $[\ce{H+}] + [\ce{OH-}] = 2 \cdot \pu{10^{-7} mol/L}$. This predicts for $\pu{120 mL}$ of neuter water $\pu{1.8 \times 10^{-8} mol}$ of $\ce{H+}$, and additional $\pu{1.8 \times 10^{-8} mol}$ of $\ce{OH-}$.  Because this is even much less, than the quantity of water newly generated by neutralization of the lye by the acid, the initial assumption to neglect the autoprotolysis of water is not invalidated.